# How to keep the edit or insert form open when showing validation message on screen

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a `RadGrid` and I call the event below when clicking update button or insert button , like below:-

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If btnUpdate.Text = "Update" Then
            If 'fail condition then
            RadWindowManagerforHelp.RadAlert("fail", 330, 180, "Validation", "")   
            e.cancelled          
            Else
            'proceed with my logic
            End If
    End If
    If btnUpdate.Text = "Insert" Then
        If 'fail condition then
            RadWindowManagerforHelp.RadAlert("fail", 330, 180, "Validation", "")   
            e.cancelled          
            Else
            'proceed with my logic
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

now how to cancel the click event, because `e.cancelled` does'nt work here and 
when I am cancelling the event then the form should not close off, after showing the `RadWindowManagerforHelp.RadAlert("fail", 330, 180, "Validation", "")`  on the screen.

Could anyone help me how to keep the Edit or Insert form (of my `RadGrid`) open when I cancel the event and  fire a validation message on the screen for failure.

ThankYou.

Comment: Cant you provide more part of the code

Comment: @ThaNet, thankyou, but now I have found an alternate way to solve my problem, so I don't think to engage you on this, Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ Jack Carothers  Ok Great! but post your solution, for future review

Comment: @ThaNet, Yea, I just used a regular expression validator on the client side , instead of using it in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            If btnUpdate.Text = "Update" Then
                    If 'fail condition' then
                    RadWindowManagerforHelp.RadAlert("fail", 330, 180,"Validation", "")   
radgrid.MasterTableView.Items[0].FireCommandEvent("CancelAll", new EventArgs())
                    Else
                    'proceed with my logic
                    End If
            End If
            If btnUpdate.Text = "Insert" Then
                If 'fail condition then
                    RadWindowManagerforHelp.RadAlert("fail", 330, 180, "Validation", "")   
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Items[0].FireCommandEvent("CancelAll", new EventArgs())
                    Else
                    'proceed with my logic
                    End If
                End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: ThankYou, but it's not working ! the form is closing off and also the `GridCommandItem` Row at the top  is disappearing !